# How to view sent time for Outlook event invitation

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I'm using Outlook Mac 2011 on OSX 10.9.5, and I cannot figure out how to see when an invitation was sent. The event invitation doesn't have the 'Sent' field like a normal email does. I tried looking through all of the menus (File, Edit, View, etc.) at the top of the screen to get more details but couldn't find anything.

How do I view the timestamp of when a meeting invitation was sent?

Comment: Please leave a useful comment when downvoting

Comment: This would be really helpful. My supervisor will send an invite the day or evening before or the day of when I've already scheduled a personal appointment the week before after looking at my calendar and I need to be able to hold them accountable in case I just absolutely cannot get out of my personal appointment(s).